# Node.js Nodemailer working locally but not when hosted A2hosting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, nodemailer

When sending emails through my form in my React frontend it works as it should locally in development, but when I host the webapp on A2hosting in production no emails are being sent or received and I am not getting any errors, on the contrary I am getting an ok status request. Anyone know what the issue and solution might be?

Server.js:

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "nl1-ss102.a2hosting.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.USER_SENDER,
    pass: process.env.PASS
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: true
  }
});

app.post("/send", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  let {
    name,
    //etc...
  } = req.body;

  await transport.sendMail({
    from: `${name}`,
    to: process.env.USER_RECEIVER,
    subject: "Subject",
    html: `
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    `
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).send('Error');
    } else {
      res.status(200).send('Success');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: can you share error logs in production?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I setup @sendGrid/mail. I would recieve the emails, but the values in the email would all be undefined. Then I saw [that] ("https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/setting-up-e-mail/using-external-smtp-servers-to-send-e-mail") a2hosting blocks external SMTP servers for clients who aren't paying for managed account's